Symfony 7 - argument that could not be resolved
I'm a beginner and I'm trying to follow a tutorial to create a blog under Symfony 7, unfortunately I find myself stuck with an error when I want to display the page of an article using his address (slug) I get:

Controller "App\Controller\ArticleController::show" requires the "$article" argument that could not be resolved. Cannot autowire argument $article of "App\Controller\ArticleController::show()": it needs an instance of "App\Entity\Article" but this type has been excluded in "config/services.yaml".

It was when I injected my Article entity into the show function of my ArticleController that the problem occurred.
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Article;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

class ArticleController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/article/{slug}', name: 'article_show')]
    public function show(Article $article): Response
    {     
        return $this->render('article/show.html.twig', [
            'article' => $article,
        ]);
    }
}

When I use the link from the home page, the route displayed is correct (with the slug).
Any idea how I could fix this? (it must be something really simple but I don't understand)
I tried to check my code, especially the entity:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Model\TimestampedInterface;
use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ArticleRepository::class)]
class Article implements TimestampedInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $slug = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $content = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $featuredText = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $createdAt = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt = null;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Category>
     */
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Category::class, mappedBy: 'articles')]
    private Collection $categories;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Comment>
     */
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Comment::class, mappedBy: 'article', orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $comments;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    private ?Media $featuredImage = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): static
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): static
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(?string $content): static
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFeaturedText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->featuredText;
    }

    public function setFeaturedText(?string $featuredText): static
    {
        $this->featuredText = $featuredText;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): static
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): static
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Category>
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category): static
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories->add($category);
            $category->addArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): static
    {
        if ($this->categories->removeElement($category)) {
            $category->removeArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Comment>
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment): static
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->add($comment);
            $comment->setArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): static
    {
        if ($this->comments->removeElement($comment)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getArticle() === $this) {
                $comment->setArticle(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFeaturedImage(): ?Media
    {
        return $this->featuredImage;
    }

    public function setFeaturedImage(?Media $featuredImage): static
    {
        $this->featuredImage = $featuredImage;

        return $this;
    }
}

You understood it, the goal is therefore to display the article page :
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ article.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
        <hr>
        {{ article.content|raw }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

Many thanks,
EDIT1: Here is the code of the home page where the link to the article page is generated. But whatever the slug indicated in the url (whether it exists or not in the database), the error message is the same.
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Accueil{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
        <main class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3 class="pb-4 mb-4 fst-italic border-bottom">Articles récents</h3>
                    <div id="articles-list">
                        {% include 'article/list.html.twig' with { articles } %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="position-sticky" style="top: 2rem;">
                        {% include 'widget/about.html.twig' %}
                        {% include 'widget/categories.html.twig' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
{% endblock %}

The template list.html.twig :
{% for article in articles %}
    {% include 'article/item.html.twig' with { article } %}
{% endfor %}

item.html.twig :
{% set article_show = path('article_show', { 'slug': article.slug }) %}

<article class="mb-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            {% if article.featuredImage %}
                    <a href="{{ article_show }}">
                        <img src="/uploads/{{ article.featuredImage.filename }}" alt="{{ article.featuredImage.altText }}" loading="lazy" width="350" height="205">
                    </a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <h2>
                <a class="text-decoration-none" href="{{ article_show }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
            </h2>
            <p>
                {{ article.createdAt|date('d M Y') }}
            </p>
            {{ article.featuredText ?: article.content|striptags|slice(0, 130) ~ '...' }}
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

EDIT2, I only have one article in the database and it does have a slug. Normally the slug cannot be null, but if I manage to get past this step, I will add a redirection in case the article cannot be found:
class ArticleController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/article/{slug}', name: 'article_show')]
    public function show(?Article $article): Response
    {
        if (!$article) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
        }
        
        return $this->render('article/show.html.twig', [
            'article' => $article,
        ]);
    }
}

For the moment if I apply this code, the article is not found and we return to the home page (this seems normal considering the error I had before that).
EDIT3, Here is the HomeController with the findAll():
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\ArticleRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_home')]
    public function index(ArticleRepository $articleRepo): Response
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'articles' => $articleRepo->findAll()
        ]);
    }
}

And ArticleRepository :
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Article;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class ArticleRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Article::class);
    }
}

EDIT4, I just tested by replacing the slug with the article id in ArticleController:
<?php
  
namespace App\Controller;
  
use App\Entity\Article;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
  
class ArticleController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/article/{id}', name: 'article_show')]
    public function show(Article $article): Response
    {
        return $this->render('article/show.html.twig', [
            'article' => $article,
        ]);
    }
}

This works perfectly using the URL containing the article id, which makes me think my code is good. However, still no solution to make it work with the slug.

show the code where you are generating the link to the article page.

Code added in my original post, thanks.

So, you are assuming slug is not null in your link generation, but slug is nullable in your entity. My assumption is that you have at least one article entry in your database where slug is null and this is the problem. Make sure all your slugs are not null and unique.

When you dump(articles), do you have a slug for all your articles ?

I only have one article in the database and it does have a slug. Normally the slug cannot be null. (I have edited my post for additional information)

in your home template, i guess your variable articles is from a findAll() method of your ArticleRepository ?

Yes, absolutely. Post edited with codes.

In your EDIT2 : You have a public function show() method and you inject an entity Article... What's is the route of this method ? DO you use a route parameter to determine the entity ?

This was just in response to craigh, to illustrate what I will do (after the problem is solved) to redirect in case of an article not found. For the moment the code used is the very first one of my post. (I edited EDIT2 with the function in its entirety to make it clearer)

And when you replace the show method with the code i provided in my answer, you still have the initial error (cannot autowire $article... )?

I just retested, same problem. I created a second article, same problem. Whatever the slug indicated in the URL (whether it exists or not in the database), same problem.

Sorry but with all these elements i really don't understand how you can still have the same error :(

Me neither, but thanks very much for your help and time.

FYI, this works perfectly by replacing the slug with the article id (see EDIT4 in my post).

After hours of struggling and exploring, I found a simple solution, just set the value "true" for "auto_mapping" in the doctrine.yaml file:
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
        report_fields_where_declared: true
        validate_xml_mapping: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true


glad to hear you found your solution. I didn't consider this because I assumed you would have used composer and flex to install doctrine which would have set this to true in its recipe. In the future, do consider composer and flex, you will find it easier to get things going.

Thanks, I think I installed composer (I don't remember about flex). But since I'm a beginner, there are some obvious things that don't come to mind right away.

You can use the MapEntity attribute to solve your problem this way :
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Article;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

class ArticleController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/article/{slug}', name: 'article_show')]
    public function show(#[MapEntity(mapping:['slug'=>'slug'])]Article $article): Response
    {     
        return $this->render('article/show.html.twig', [
            'article' => $article,
        ]);
    }
}

The mapEntity attribute will allow Symfony to find the entity with the slug you have in your route parameter.

Thanks for your reply. I unfortunately get the same error. Whatever the slug indicated (whether it exists in the database or not), same error.

Like @craig said show us the code where you generate the link because i don' understand how you can still have the same error

I just edited my first post, thanks.
